# ALL_TAB_PRIVS gives different results from package context

Tags: oracle12c, sql-grant

I'm trying to use the view `ALL_TAB_PRIVS` to determine whether a certain grant exists for a table for a specific user. Querying the view itself works as intended, but when I'm querying it from a procedure within a package it misses a grantee.
Here's the code snippet I use:

```
declare
    procedure foo is
    begin
        for s in (select * from all_tab_privs p
                where p.table_schema = 'B' and p.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME') loop
            dbms_output.put_line(s.grantee);
        end loop;    
    end;
begin
    tester.foo;
    dbms_output.put_line('--');
    foo;
end;
```

I run this code from schema `A` and I want to check whether schema `C` has an `SELECT` grant on table `TABLE_NAME` in schema `B`. `TESTER` is a package in schema `A` which has a procedure `foo` which does the same thing as the free procedure in the code snippet. However the output is:

```
A
--
A
C
```

So the packaged procedure is missing the grant for `C`. How is this possible? Is the view built differntly depending on where it's called from? I checked the documentation, but couldn't find a hint on why this is happening.

Comment: Could it be the difference between INVOKER's rights an DEFINER's rights? See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1523186194900

Comment: ... or perhaps privileges acquired through a direct grant to the user vs. via granting a role. Procedures, whether in a package or not, enjoy only the privileges assigned to the package owner via a direct grant; privileges acquired by the owner via roles do not apply to procedures and functions, whether in a package or not.